# Add property to all objects of json array

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have this Employee DTO

```
Class Employee
{
   int Id {get; set;}
   string Name {get; set;}
}
```

In my code I'm getting collection of Employee objects & serializing it as shown below

```
string JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees); // where employees is IEnumerable<Employee>
```

The JsonString that i get here is

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"John"},
{"Id":2,"Name":"Mark"},
{"Id":3,"Name":"Pete"}]
```

Now I want to add one more property to all these objects present in the json array

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"John","Department":"Computer Science"},
{"Id":2,"Name":"Mark","Department":"Computer Science"},
{"Id":3,"Name":"Pete","Department":"Computer Science"}]
```

The challenge is that i don't want to add extra property "Department" to my existing Employee Dto.

Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an intermediate [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) from your employees and serialize that:

```
var extendedEmployees = employees.Select(employee => new
                        {
                            employee.Id,
                            employee.Name, 
                            Department = "Computer Science",
                        }

var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(extendedEmployees)
```